# Linear ODE Question (Repeated roots)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\displaystyle
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle
\frac {dA}{dt} = 2A - B \\
\displaystyle
\frac {dB}{dt} = A
\end{cases}
$$

With Initial Conditions,
$$
\begin{cases}
A(0) = A_0 \\
B(0) = B_0
\end{cases}
$$

I differentiated $dA/dt$ and substituted $dB/dt$ into $d^2A/dt^2$ and found the roots to be repeated roots, $r_1=r_2=1$ leading to a general solution of 
$$A=e^t(C1 + C2)$$

### How do I solve further?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that
$$A''-2A'+A=0 \implies r^2-2r+1=0 \implies r=1$$
Then you have the solution
$$A(t)=c_1e^t+c_2te^t$$
And for $B(t)$
$$B(t)=c_3e^t+c_4te^t$$
Multiply by t the second solution ...

Then apply the initial conditions to find $c_1,c_2$

I let you finish, I am sure you can solve the system...

---

Edit

You should end with this result  if I made no mistake

$$
\begin{cases}
A(t)=A_0e^t+(A_0-B_0)te^t \\
B(t)=B_0e^t+(A_0-B_0)te^t 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But im struggling because when i substitute A(t) into dB/dt and intergrate, will there be a third constant? And if there is, then there would be 3 unknowns, C1, C2 and C3. How would u advice solving it?

Comment: @LucasTan   ...try to do for B what you did for A  you have that $$B''=2B'-B \implies B(t)=c_3e^t+c_4te^t$$

Comment: I managed to produce the B(t) general solution. 


$B" - 2B' + B = 0$,


$B(t) = c_3e^t + c_4 t e^t$,


$B(0) = c_3$.


$B(t) = B_0 + c_4 t e^t$,

Similarly for A(t),

$A(t) = A_0 e^t + C_2 t e^t $,

How do I solve for C2 and C4?

Comment: Update.

I differentiated the general solution of B to get dB/dt. Since dB/dt = A, compare general solutions to obtain C2 and C4.

Comment: @LucasTan I added the final solution ... you are on the right path to solve the system...

Answer (score 1):

Your $$A=e^t(C1 + C2)$$ should have been $$A=e^t(C_1 + C_2t)$$

You can find $B$ from $$ B=2A-A'$$ and find constants from initial values.